# wanting to write a txt with Tkinter entry box

Tags: csv, tkinter

just trying to allow users to write in their name and email address for it to be then written into a text file. There are no error messages that pop up it's just, it isn't writing into the file. also, the message box isn't coming up with (+ aname + '\n' + full email + '\n') it just comes up with the message. Cheers

```
import tkinter as tk #shortening tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import csv
from tkinter import *


def store_customers():
    aname = name.get()
    aemail = email.get()
    aemailaddress = emailaddress.get()

    
    fullemail = aemail + aemailaddress
    print(fullemail)
    
    if (name == "" or email == ""):
        print('Error')
        messagebox.showerror('error',"their was some issur with your information")
        email.set('')
        name.set('')
    
    else:
        result = messagebox.askquestion('question', 'Your about to enter yor information \n' + aname + '\n' + fullemail + '\n' ) 
        
        if (result == 'yes'):
            print('here')
            with open ('customersdata.txt', 'a') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow([aname, fullemail])
            csvfile.close()
            
        else:
            name.set('')
            email.set('')
            
                      
name = StringVar()
email = StringVar()
emailaddress = StringVar()


name = tk.Entry(frame4, text="",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',24)  )
name.place(x= 400, y = 600)

email = tk.Entry(frame4, text="",  bg = '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',24) )
email.place(x= 400, y = 660)

list1 = ['@yahoo.com','@bing.com','@jpc.vic.edu.au', '@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com' ]
emailaddres= OptionMenu(frame4,emailaddress,*list1)
emailaddres.config(height = 2 )
emailaddress.set('@***.***.edu.au')
emailaddres.place(x= 685, y= 660)

storebtn = tk.Button(frame4, text = 'complete', bg= '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',24), command = store_customers)
storebtn.place (x = 430, y= 700)


tk.Label(frame4, text= "Your name", bg= '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',24)).place(x = 260, y = 600)
tk.Label(frame4, text= "email address", bg= '#F0EAD6', font=('Arial',24)).place(x = 240, y = 660)

frame4.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code with Tkinter.

```
import csv
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


def save():
    nome_to_save = namevalue.get()
    email_to_save = emailvalue.get()

    if len(nome_to_save) == 0 or len(email_to_save) == 0:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'You need to enter name and e-mail!')
    else:
        with open('customersdata.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow([nome_to_save, email_to_save])
        csvfile.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Success', f'Information of {nome_to_save} saved!')


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Write CSV")

namevalue = tkinter.StringVar()
emailvalue = tkinter.StringVar()

tkinter.Label(window, text = "Name").grid(row = 0)
name = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=namevalue).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

tkinter.Label(window, text = "E-mail").grid(row = 1)
email = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=emailvalue).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

tkinter.Button(window, text="Save", command = save).grid(row = 2)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably receive some error, right?

You have imported `tkinter.messagebox` as `box`.
So replace `messagebox.showerror` and `messagebox.askquestion` with `box.showerror` and `box.askquestion`

PS: I am new here, so I cannot comment. Sorry!

Comment: cheers lad. solves half the problems as it shows the info in the message box. unfortunately, however, it doesn't  doesn't write into the txt file. @Ishaan Jog

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you.

```
import csv

def store_customers(name, email):
    if name == "" or email == "":
        print('Error, i need name and email')
    else:
        with open('customersdata.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow([name, email])
        csvfile.close()

#store_customers('', '')
store_customers('Diego', 'diego@false.io')
store_customers('Ana Maria', 'ana.maria@myemail.io')
store_customers('Julia Neau', 'jneau@cool.io')
```

Comment: sorry man but I need the code for Tkinter not python shell. also I want usesr to enter their own data.